# .Equals() not working while iterating hashmap

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrtoh.png)I have a hashmap  which I need to compare values of the String array to certain strings and remove those which are equal. In this instance I know the String [] at a certain index = "RES", but when I iterate through the if (equality) statement returns false each time. Do I have to worry about overriding .equals() when simply extending hashmap? What is wrong with the if statement?

```
public void filter(){
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String[]>> iter = this.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry = iter.next();
        String[] current = entry.getValue();
        if(current[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("RES")){  
            this.remove(entry.getKey());
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.remove()`?

Comment: use debugger , see what the value of current[0], string equality has no problem

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the `if` statement itself, but you're going to get a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you use `remove(key)` instead of `iter.remove()`.

Comment: Just solved the ConcurrentModificationException. But when current[0] = "RES", (current[0].trim(0).equalsIgnoreCase("RES") ) is returning false.

Comment: @AmerQarabsa, when in debugger the value of current[0] = "RES" multiple times, but the program still doesn't enter the if statement. Any other possible debugging suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
this.remove(entry.getKey());
```

With:

```
iter.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks! I just caught that as well. The concurrent modification exception doesn't seem to be the problem. When current[0] = "RES", (current[0].trim(0).equalsIgnoreCase("RES") ) is returning false.